# NodeJS + Axios instance + Cached between requests

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

Current setup is VueJS + SSR, but any React JS solutions probably work too.

I have a file called axios.js in which I create a new axios instance and set the apropiate Authorization headers.

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.foo = 123;
});

const instance = axios.create();
instance.verylongunexistingattribute = new Date().toUTCString()

instance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.foo = 456;
});

axios.get('/foo'); // config.foo === 123 -> true
instance.get('/foo'); // config.foo === 456 -> true

export { instance, createInstance, initializeApiV2 }
```

Seems fine to me, then in my file where I do the AJAX requests I simply do:

```
import axios from '@/src/api/axios'

let fetchUserProperties = () => {

    console.log("axios:instance", axios.verylongunexistingattribute)
    console.log("axios:instance.request", new Date().toUTCString())

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        axios.get(`/profile/properties`)
        .then((result) => {
            resolve(result.data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            reject(error)
        })

    });
}
```

Just to remember, this works perfect in the browser, but fails miserably on node.

Why does it fail: [enter link description here](https://medium.com/@iaincollins/how-not-to-create-a-singleton-in-node-js-bd7fde5361f5)

Basically, the instance created in axios.js is being cached by node, so that following request made by diferent users end up using the same instance. And if a requestInterceptor with the token has already been defined then it might show other users data :(

I can't get my head around it, as I can't just return a function which creates a new instance of axios everytime it is called.

How can I create an axios instance which will only live for 1 request?

I tried to explain it as best as I could, if you need more info just ask.

Comment: I am wondering this myself as I attach an authorization header which gets set on each request. I am worried the authorization header will persist between node requests, but I think I'm technically ok since node is single threaded. I would feel safer if it was one axios instance per node request. My best guess would be to use something like your `createInstance` to generate a new axios instance on each request and pass that around (if needed). From my understanding any variable in nodes global scope persists through multiple requests because node is a continuous running process.